# Get the weekday from a Date object or date string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, function, date, dayofweek

I have a date string in (yyyy-mm-dd) format, how can I get the weekday name from it?

**Example:**

- For the string "2013-07-31", the output would be "Wednesday"
- For today's date using `new Date()`, the output would be based on the current day of week

Answer (score 37):

#### Use this function, comes with date string validation:

If you include this function somewhere in your project,

```
// Accepts a Date object or date string that is recognized by the Date.parse() method
function getDayOfWeek(date) {
  const dayOfWeek = new Date(date).getDay();    
  return isNaN(dayOfWeek) ? null : 
    ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][dayOfWeek];
}
```

You will be able to use it anywhere easily like this:

```
getDayOfWeek( "2013-07-31" )
> "Wednesday"

getDayOfWeek( new Date() ) // or
getDayOfWeek( Date.now() )
> // (will return today's day. See demo jsfiddle below...)
```

If invalid date string is used, a null will be returned.

```
getDayOfWeek( "~invalid string~" );
> null
```

Valid date strings are based on the [Date.parse() method as described in the MDN JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/fo1nnsgp/

---

Of course you can also use the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) plugin, *especially* if timezones are required.

Answer (score 15):

Here are one-liner solutions but please check the support first.

```js
let current = new Date();
let today = current.toLocaleDateString('en-US',{weekday: 'long'});
console.log(today);

let today2 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {weekday: 'long'}).format(current);
console.log(today2)
```

[Docs for Intl.DateTimeFormat object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

[Docs for localeDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 12):

Use below code:

```
var gsDayNames = [
  'Sunday',
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday'
];

var d = new Date("2013-07-31");
var dayName = gsDayNames[d.getDay()];
//dayName will return the name of day
```

Answer (score 0):

find all weekdays from current days.

```
let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
let dates = [];

days.forEach((day,index)=>{
    if(index == new Date().getDay()){
            for(let i = index-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // console.log("days is "+day+" => "+(new Date().getDate() - i))
        var date = new Date();
        dates.push({date: new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - i)).toString(), days: days[i]+"-"+i})
    }
        var date = new Date();
        dates.push({date: new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate())).toString(), days: days[index]+"-"+index})
    // console.log("Today is "+day+" => "+new Date().getDate())
            for(let i = index+1; i < days.length; i++) {
            // console.log("day is "+day+" => "+(new Date().getDate() + i))
        var date = new Date();
                    // add a day
        dates.push({date: new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + i)).toString(), days: days[i]+"-"+i})
        }
    }
})

console.log(dates)
```