# How to convert time in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, time

I have tried to convert my time and date from `06/15/2017 02:45 PM` to `Monday, June 6, 2017 02:45 PM` Is there a way to go about this?

This is what i tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Date = {{ "06/15/2017T02:45Z" | date : "EEEE, MMMM d, y h:mm a" }}</p>

</div>

<p>The date can be a date object, milliseconds, or, like in this example, a datetime string.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

it works only when i try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Date = {{ "06/15/2017T02:45Z" | date : "EEEE, MMMM d, y h:mm a" }}</p>

</div>

<p>The date can be a date object, milliseconds, or, like in this example, a datetime string.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your code, please?

Comment: Use a JS library to do it, such as MomentJS.

Comment: CODE?? Please??

Comment: You can't convert anything with HTML.  Did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: All i basically want to achieve is converting the time stored in my database as _06/15/2017 02:45 PM_ to something like this _Monday, June 6, 2017 02:45 PM_ before displaying it on the site front end maybe with javascript or php

Comment: @RandomDeveloper  i have updated my questions

Comment: @MohamedAbbas please i have updated my question, kindly review it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ddj1weez/3/

You can use a switch case statement to compare the first part of the month and then just append the rest on the date to it:

```
switch(month){
    case "01":
    month_written = "Jan";
    break;
  case "02":
    month_written = "Feb";
    break;
  case "03":
    month_written = "Mar";
    break;
  case "04":
    month_written = "Apr";
    break;
  case "05":
    month_written = "May";
    break;
  case "06":
    month_written = "Jun";
    break;
  case "07":
    month_written = "Jul";
    break;
  case "08":
    month_written = "Aug";
    break;
  case "09":
    month_written = "Sep";
    break;
  case "10":
    month_written = "Oct";
    break;
  case "11":
    month_written = "Nov";
    break;
  case "12":
    month_written = "Dec";
    break;
}
```

But as one of the comments said, you should consider implementing a JS library. 
https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Nice, this really worked the magic, but how do i add the day like monday?

Comment: Didn't add that part, but I'll leave that up to you. A bit of help: you can use this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17964363/3422027) to add that last part to the date. Hope this helps you out! :)