# how to get weekday in number from date in angularJS binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to get "day of the week" from specific date in angular binding.
Expected result like:

```
date=07/26/2017 
so above date day is "wednesday"
expected result is "3" b'coz above date weekDay is "3"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the weekday from a Date object or date string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964170/get-the-weekday-from-a-date-object-or-date-string-using-javascript)

Comment: i tried <div ng-bind="myDate|date:'EEE'"></div> It return result in day name like "Sun-Sat" format but i expect result in week day number.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
var t = new Date('07/26/2017')
t.getDay() // it will return 3
```

This is a working snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.myDate = '07/26/2017';
});

app.filter('customdate', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var t = new Date(input);
    return t.getDay();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{myDate|customdate}}
  </div>
```

Comment: I need it on angular binding side, so JavaScript functions are not work in angular binding

Comment: @WinodPatel can you make a fiddle?

Comment: <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td ng-bind="myDate|date:'EEE'"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

Comment: @WinodPatel Check my answer. Its in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple date prototype methods like `getDay()`  Here is the example.

```
var d = new Date('07/26/2017');
var day = d.getDay()'
```

It will simple return `3` i.e. day of the week.

NOTE: Date constructor should be initialized with the standard date formats.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can try this.

```
<div ng-app="dateApp" ng-controller="dateController">
   <p> {{ result }} </p>
</div>
```

*Controller*

```
var dtApp = angular.module('dateApp', []);
dtApp.controller(
    'dateController',
    function ($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.result = new Date().getDay();
    }
);
```