# How to get day of week based on Date

Tags: javascript

I have date in format "YYYY-MM-DD"
2018-08-26 and i want something like that 
date.getDay() => return (0-6)
and using switch case loop that 0 let dayOfWeek == 'Sun' ...

Is exist some tip get String representation of day ?

Comment: And another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964170/get-the-weekday-from-a-date-object-or-date-string-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with the weekdays

```
let weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

and then get the weekday for your date like this

```
let weekday = weekdays[date.getDay()];
```

Comment: Duplicate answer on a duplicate question