# How to get day name with date in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get day name with date which is in string format in nodejs can anyone help how this can be done?

```
 let gameDate = bidDatarray[0].gameDate;// date : 27/12/2019
 console.log( gameDate.getDay());
```

This gives error that gameDate.getDay() is not a function

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964170/get-the-weekday-from-a-date-object-or-date-string-using-javascript

Comment: yes i have  tried this does  not help

Comment: what error did you get?? I think you have to look look into date format??

Comment: done this by using node moment module. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date('12/27/2019').getDay()` you need to swap day with month.